# linq to sql error when trying to insert

Tags: linq-to-sql

Im trying to do an simple insert but am stuck with an error...

```
Error   10  The type arguments for method 'System.Data.Linq.Table<RequestSystem.User>.InsertAllOnSubmit<TSubEntity>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSubEntity>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

My code is

```
        `UserModel User = new UserModel();
        User.MudID = a[1];
        User.Name = Session["username"].ToString();
        User.Email = Session["email"].ToString();`


        DataClasses1DataContext dt = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        dt.Users.InsertAllOnSubmit(User);

        dt.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following instead:

```
dt.Users.InsertOnSubmit(User);
```

That will insert a single instance of your object.  Using InsertAllOnSubmit expects a collection of objects

Comment: Using c#, I thing the hyphen was put there when the mod edited the post

Comment: Please see new answer.